# how to update order table after checkout

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

i'm developing carrier module for my project.i have to update a new column after checkout.

inside my module ,i want to call some hook immediately after order placed to get `order id` .

i have used below hooks.but no luck.

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params){
$order_id=$params['newOrderStatus']->id;
}

public function hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate($params){
$order_id=$params['newOrderStatus']->id;
}

public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params){
$order_id=$params['newOrderStatus']->id;
}
```

how to get order id into my module,when user on order confirmation page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register one of this hooks before ?
It must work as a charm inside module class with :

```
 $this->registerHook('displayOrderConfirmation');
```

to get the order id it's simple :

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params){
    $order_id = $params['order']->id;
}
```